# Inconsistent default logarithm base in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

I've been experiencing an issue where SQLite's log function returns inconsistent results between PyCharm's Query console and when running the same query in python environments. The code where I first spotted this used SQLAlchemy, but it can also be seen using sqlite3 module here:

```
>>> from sqlite3 import connect
>>> cur = connect("data/db.sqlite3").cursor()
>>> print(cur.execute("select log(10);").fetchall())
[(0.9999999999999999,)]
```

When executed in python, `log(x)` is always evaluated as base 10 logarithm, as specified in [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#log):

> Return the base-10 logarithm for X. Or, for the two-argument version, return the base-B logarithm of X.

However, when I run the same query in PyCharm's query console, it returns the natural log.

```
+-----------------+
|log(10)          |
+-----------------+
|2.302585092994046|
+-----------------+
```

Why is this happening, and how do I ensure that my queries are evaluated consistently across all environments?

Comment: Could this PyCharm be installing its own version of a `log()` function? SQLite coming with one built in is pretty recent...

Comment: You skipped the part of the linked quote that says that SQLite and PostGreSQL compute a base-10 logarithm, but *most other SQL engines* compute a natural logarithm. PyCharm doesn't seem to be doing anything strange here; it's simply not the logarithm you expect.

Comment: If you want consistency, you'll have to be explicit about which base you want to use with the two-argument form of `log`.